# Setting up a website to run on my local network

Tags: javascript, python, flask

So basically i made a website that i want to make available on my home network so that i can control a python Qapplication with it. I used xampp to make it available on the home network and other Pcs can open the website but when they input text it doesnt get sent. When i try this on the same pc that's running the python program and the xampp program it works perfectly.
This is the js code for the website:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const uploadBtn = document.getElementById('uploadBtn');
  uploadBtn.addEventListener('click', handleUpload);
});

function handleUpload() {
  const inputText = document.getElementById('inputText').value;

  // Create an HTTP request object
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  // Define the request parameters
  xhr.open('POST', 'http://192.168.0.104:5000', true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  // Handle the response from the server
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
          alert('Text uploaded successfully!');
      }
  };

  // Send the request with the user input as the data
  xhr.send('inputText=' + encodeURIComponent(inputText));
}
```

and this is the relevant part from the python code

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def handle_request():
    global to_do

    if request.method == 'POST':
        input_text = request.form.get('inputText')
        to_do = input_text
        print(to_do)

    return 'OK'

def run_flask():
    app.run(host='192.168.0.104', port=5000)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    threading.Thread(target=run_flask).start()

    app2 = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window(1920, 1080, 20, 220, 10)
    sys.exit(app2.exec())
```

I appreciate any help.

i expected the website to behave the same on other pcs but although the website loaded it did not send the input text.

Comment: Make sure you don't have a firewall on your PC that's blocking connections to port 5000.

Comment: Is there an error in the JavaScript console?

Comment: If Flask is running on a different port than the HTML, this is considered cross-origin and you have to implement CORS.

Comment: no there isn't any

Comment: What do you see in the Network tab when it sends the XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: Sorry i'm kinda new to this, which network tab do you mean?

Comment: In the browser's Developer Tools. When you're debugging JavaScript, you should always have this open.

Comment: So i checked and when i send a text a new line appears and it says that type:xhr and status pending then status failed

Comment: Add logging to the Flask app. Do you see the requests coming in? If not, something is blocking it, which is why I think there may be a firewall.

Comment: Ok so now i turned off every firewall and it just says cors error without pending

Comment: Which I mentioned above. Since Flask is on a different port from the website, you need to send Access-Control-Allow-Origin. There are many previous questions about CORS, I'm not going to repeat the solutions here.